# IntelliJ Java - Selenium webdriver can't find element - dynamic id

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, webdriver

I'm a beginner at test automation, and now i'm trying to find an element.

The element looks like:

```html
<a class="iceCmdLnk" href="javascript:;" id="personalDataForm:j_idt2380" onblur="setFocus('');" onclick="var form=formOf(this);form['personalDataForm:j_idcl'].value='personalDataForm:j_idt2380';iceSubmit(form,this,event);form['personalDataForm:j_idcl'].value='';return false;" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);"><span class="iceOutTxt simpleBoldText" id="personalDataForm:j_idt2381" style="text-decoration: underline;">van</span></a>
<span class="iceOutTxt simpleBoldText" id="personalDataForm:j_idt2381" style="text-decoration: underline;">Click here</span>
```

personalDataForm:j_idt2381
The ID is changing dynamically: fix value-> personalDataForm:j_idt dynamic numbers->2381

Tried a couple solutions :

```js
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[3]/a/span")).click();
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'personalDataForm:j_idt')]")).click();
```

but i get this error message:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[3]/a/span"}

If i'm try to locate element with selenium, successfully find the in the front end page.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its an internal web application in my company. Should I provide more data of the element?

Comment: To provide a correct element locator in most times we need to see not the element itself but the entire block of elements it is inside or preferable the entire page

Comment: your locator  works fine , see if the element is inside iframe

Comment: Try to find any element, for example by tagName "a". If it fails as well, check implicit wait and/or iframes.

Comment: Thank you guys!! The iFrame was my target. Solution:         
        webDriver.switchTo().frame(webDriver.findElement(By.id("iFrame_ID")));
        webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[3]/a/span")).click();
        webDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();